# Открытие doc, docx, odf, xlsx файла в терминале linux

Tags: кодировка, doc, docx, терминал

Вопрос заключается в следующем: "Существует ли такие программы, позволяющие открыть doc, docx, odf файлы в терминале linux?".
Понимаю, что теоретически это не возможно, в силу отсутствие возможности программной смены шрифта в терминале. Но! Что если, мне нужно, к примеру, тупо прочитать текст из файла, а под рукой нету десктопной машины? Или можно такой вариант: программа преобразовывает doc, docx, odf файл в tex-файл.
P.S.: я так полагаю, что этот вариант открытия подобных файлов будет еще и экономнее десктопного относительно памяти.

С xlsx и подобными этому файлами тоже такой же вопрос встревает. Папа как-то рассказывал просто, что когда еще не было десктопных осей и граф оболочек, они использовали вместо doc-ов какую-то dos-овскую консольную прогу, и какие-то таблицы вместо excel-ей.
Буду благодарен за ответ.

**UPD**: Вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Когда не было графических оболочек, тогда и и форматы были другие. Чем-то отчасти похожие на современный markdown

Файлы же конечно можно прочитать. Но именно прочитать - предварительно конвертировав в текстовый формат. Так Excel файлы можно перевести в CSV - а дальше смотри хоть в less, хоть awk или sed дальше преобразуй.

Файл Word конвертируются в обычный TXT - только текст и никакого форматирования. Можно и в RTF - тут оформление сохранится, но чтобы их читать нужен определенный навык :)

А с практической точки зрения задача довольно актуальная. Постоянно приходится решать задачи типа "У нас есть прайс-лист в Excel - мы хотим его автоматически загружать на сайта в базу данных". Соответственно помимо утилит консоли есть и куча библиотек под разные языки программирования - позволяющих открыть, прочитать, изменить и сохранить файлы этих форматов без взякого GUI.

Comment: А не могли бы вы дать название такой программки или придется писать конвертор самому? И есть ли что-то вроде мануала, как читать rtf?

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вопрос закрыт.

Answer (score 3):

для просмотра *doc* можно использовать *catdoc*, *antiword* и множество аналогичных программ.

для просмотра *docx* можно использовать, например, *docx2txt*.

для просмотра *odf/odt* можно использовать, например, *odt2txt*.

для просмотра *xlsx* можно использовать, например, *xlsx2csv*.

---

все перечисленные программы имеются в одноимённых пакетах в репозитории дистрибутива *debian* операционной системы *gnu/linux*. наверняка они есть в уже собранном виде и в репозиториях других популярных дистрибутивов. в крайнем случае можно скомпилировать — п.о. свободное, исходники общедоступны.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос уже давно закрыт, но я сейчас нарыл дополнительное решение:
Можно написать свое приложение, которое читает excel файл и выводит его содержимое в терминал с помощью java-библиотеки apache-poi.